# Getting node-config related typescript error when compiling

Tags: node-config

I have a expressjs project running Typescript and also using the `node-config` package.

When i try and compile my typescript with:
`./node_modules/.bin/tsc --project ./server/tsconfig.json`

I get the following type error:

`server/index.ts(15,33): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ name: {}; dialect: string; host: {}; port: {}; username: {}; password: {}; validateOnly: false; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ISequelizeConfig | ISequelizeValidationOnlyConfig'.
  Type '{ name: {}; dialect: string; host: {}; port: {}; username: {}; password: {}; validateOnly: false; }' is not assignable to type 'ISequelizeConfig'.
    Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
      Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

Can anyone help me to see why this is failing?

Thanks

Comment: According to your paste, the error is in `/server/index.ts` on line 15. What happens on that line? Assuming that's where it's loading `node-config`, than it would be relevant to see your config files-- or an anonymized version of them. You might also search the `node-config` issue tracker and wiki on Github for TypeScript-related issues.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?